# Q:how to declare a property of Byte[] in iOS?

Tags: ios, arrays, properties, byte, attr

I have a method which need receive a `Byte[]` :

In the `.h` file:

```
- (void)setPC1_APPKEY:(Byte[] )pC1_APPKEY;
```

In the `.m` file:

I want to own a `Byte[]` property to save it.

But when I declare the property like this:

`@property (nonatomic, assign) Byte PC1_APPKEY[];`

It shows error:`property cannot have array or function type'Byte[]'`

And so I set it to attribute like this:

```
{
    Byte PC1_APPKEY[];
}
```

It shows error:`Field has Incomplete type ‘Byte[]’`

How can I get the `Byte[]` ? thanks.

Comment: Use Byte *, everything is a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Pointer like this

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) Byte *PC1_APPKEY;
```

all files

.h

```
//
//  ocViewController.h
//  testTableViewHeader
//
//  Created by 刷脸卡 on 10/11/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 曾祥林. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController
- (void)setPC1_APPKEY:(Byte[] )pC1_APPKEY;
@end
```

.m

```
//
//  ocViewController.m
//  testTableViewHeader
//
//  Created by 刷脸卡 on 10/11/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 曾祥林. All rights reserved.
//

#import "TestViewController.h"

@interface TestViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, assign) Byte *PC1_APPKEY;
@end

@implementation TestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *testString = @"1234567890";
    NSData *testData = [testString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    self.PC1_APPKEY = (Byte *)[testData bytes];
    for(int i=0;i<[testData length];i++){
        printf("testByte = %d\n",self.PC1_APPKEY[i]);
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)setPC1_APPKEY:(Byte [])pC1_APPKEY{
    self.PC1_APPKEY = pC1_APPKEY;
}

@end
```

Comment: 怎么能这样，这里面貌似中国人还不少哦，先前还看见了另外一个也是特么注释还是中文的

Comment: 以后问问题分时间，特么中国人多的时候就全用问，省的老想用啥单词，特么本来英文就特差

Comment: 加我QQ撒，我已经加你了  或者429801517